# Add custom headers to SOAP request using zeep.Client Python

Tags: python-3.x, soap, zeep

I have problems creating and adding custom headers to SOAP header. If I write a RAW request it works, but I want to use zeep library in Python3

I tried to add theese headers

```
header = xsd.Element(
        'headerMDMPeticio',xsd.ComplexType([
            xsd.Element('idSistemaOrigen',xsd.String()),
            xsd.Element(
                'headerMidominio',xsd.ComplexType([
                    xsd.Element('usuariConnectat',xsd.String()),
                    xsd.Element('rolUsuariConnectat',xsd.String())
                ])
            )
        ])
    )
header_value = header(headerMidominio={'usuariConnectat':'user','rolUsuariConnectat':'roleExample'})
```

extracted from theese book https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-zeep/master/python-zeep.pdf (page 18)

Here is the python code for generate XML that I'm using

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin,PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, TemplateView, FormView
from zeep import Client, xsd
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
from lxml import etree
from .models import MDMRelCodiProjecte

def codiprojecte_list(request):
    codis = MDMRelCodiProjecte.objects.filter(data_esborrat__isnull=True).order_by('data_modificat')
    #Consultamos al servicio SOAP
    url_service = "https://services.dev.midominio.edu/soa/extern/SOAP12/MDMCodisProjectes/v01_00"
    url_wsdl    = url_service+"/?wsdl"

    soapClient = Client(url_wsdl,wsse=UsernameToken('developer_user','miPasswordEnTextoPlano'))
    soapClient.service._binding_options['address'] = url_service # En el WSDL viene con una URL incorrecta --> ponemos la correcta!

    id_service = '100045976'
    soapDataUserPass = {'Username':'developer_user','Password':'miPasswordEnTextoPlano'}

    node = soapClient.create_message(soapClient.service, 'consultarCodiProjecteMDM',id_service)
    print (node)
    print (etree.tostring(node,pretty_print=True))

    #print(soapClient.service.consultarCodiProjecteMDM(id_service,soapDataUsosDada))
    return render(request, 'codi_projecte/codiprojecte_list.html', {'codis':codis})
```

Expected (extracted from SOAP UI), focus on v01:headerMDMPeticio and children of this node. Inside body I also need to ADD v012:usosDada to request.

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://services.dev.midominio.edu/soa/servei/CodisProjectesMDM/v01_00/consultarCodiProjecteMDMInput"
Content-Length: 1811
Host: services.dev.midominio.edu
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v01="http://midominio.edu/soa/esquema/ElementsComunsMDM/v01_00" xmlns:v011="http://midominio.edu/soa/esquema/ElementsComuns/v01_01" xmlns:v012="http://midominio.edu/soa/servei/MDMCodisProjectes/v01_00">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-6e6f6d657365617363757472656e6f6F">
                <wsse:Username>developer_user</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">miPasswordEnTextoPlano</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">rndomDataHash+rndomtxt==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2019-06-05T08:20:45.644Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <v01:headerMDMPeticio>
            <v01:idSistemaOrigen>1</v01:idSistemaOrigen>
            <v01:headerMidominio>
                <v011:usuariConnectat>usuarioPlataforma</v011:usuariConnectat>
                <v011:rolUsuariConnectat>pepitoPalote</v011:rolUsuariConnectat>
            </v01:headerMidominio>
        </v01:headerMDMPeticio>
    </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <v012:consultarCodiProjecteMDMInput>
         <v012:idMDM>100045976</v012:idMDM>
         <v012:usosDada>
            <v01:arrayUsosDeDadaItem>
               <v01:tipus>Prova persona</v01:tipus>
            </v01:arrayUsosDeDadaItem>
         </v012:usosDada>
      </v012:consultarCodiProjecteMDMInput>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope
```

And this is that I generate with my Python code

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>developer_user</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">miPasswordEnTextoPlano</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <ns0:consultarCodiProjecteMDMInput xmlns:ns0="https://services.dev.midominio.edu/soa/servei/MDMCodisProjectes/v01_00">
            <ns0:idMDM>100045976</ns0:idMDM>
        </ns0:consultarCodiProjecteMDMInput>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 6):

Zeep requires that you define your headers in the special kwarg `_soapheaders`, like so:

```
from zeep import Client

wsdl = 'http://localhost/services/Assets?wsdl'

client = Client(wsdl)

request_data = {
    "InterplayPathURI" : "interplay://TGAvid/Projects",
    "SearchGroup" : {
        "Operator" : "OR",
        "AttributeCondition" : {
            "Condition" : "EQUALS",
            "Attribute" :
            {"Group" : "SYSTEM",
             "Name": "Type",
             "_value_1": "masterclip"},
            },
        },
    "MaxResults" : "500",
}

header_value = {
    "credentialsHeader" : {
        "Username" : "administrator",
        "Password" : "Avid123"
    }
}

result = client.service.Search(**request_data, _soapheaders=header_value)
```